# ASP.NET Core + Antiforgery + jQuery Ajax POST + Nginx - 400 Bad Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, nginx, antiforgerytoken

This topic has a lot of *similar* questions but none of them addresses the specific issue I'm facing today.

The affected environment is:

- ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app (v3.1.9 Runtime)
- Ubuntu Server v20.04 Focal
- Nginx web server (v1.18.0) configured as proxy pass for Kestrel

The issue occurs when issuing an Ajax POST using jQuery (other JS frameworks fail as well), which hits 400 - Bad Request due to the Antiforgerytoken not being properly validated.

**The issue is not related to the Antiforgery token missing**, since it gets properly added to the Ajax call header fields and/or form fields as well in the appropriate way:

```
@inject IAntiforgery antiforgery 
@{
    var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context);
}

[...]

$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "@tokenSet.HeaderName": "@tokenSet.RequestToken"
    },
    data: {
        "@tokenSet.FormFieldName": "@tokenSet.RequestToken"
    },

    [...]

});
```

The above pattern to set the Antiforgery token is proved to be working fine, to the point that the call gets accepted in development and even in production when accessing Kestrel directly (no 400 error if Nginx is not involved).

As a matter of fact, the problem seems related to this specific Nginx issue:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17081
- https://github.com/dperson/nginx/pull/36

In the first thread there's also a workaround, which relies upon the following Nginx settings:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

Unfortunately, that suggested workaround is not working for me.

Any clue?

---

**UPDATE**: I eventually managed to fix this. The problem was related to a dot that I had in both the header name and the cookie name:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-MyApp.Namespace";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-MyApp.Namespace";
});
```

which was enough to cripple everything. Thanks to  Mike Bogolepov for the answer, the issue was not the underscore he suggested but that suggestion was still good enough to point me in the right direction: thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with the same problem, i want to suppose:

First, does your application use Aspnet Core DataProtection ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Wrong validation can be related to it.

Second, we have a header with underscores and nginx cut it from request to Kestrel. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers. If you use k8s with ingress in your production:  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-underscores-in-headers.

Do you override header name or nulled it in Startup.cs (`AddAntiforgery()` method)?

Comment: I had a dot in the header name AND form field name, which basically crippled both of them: you "underscore" suggestion was good enough to point me in the right direction and finally I managed to fix this issue: thank you!